# GEKKO - How to fix Python Gekko Max Equation error - number of elements

Tags: python, gekko

I have developed a script using Gekko optimisation functions. The script below runs for a number of elements. I tested the optimisation algorithm for 20 and 47 cells (shapefile dataset) and the script achieves a solution. However, when I test for a bigger dataset, with 160 elements, for example, the following error message is shown:

“APM model error: string >       15000 characters

Consider breaking up the line into multiple equations”

I read some suggestions to fix this problem. I tried using m.sum, but the problem persists.

Please, could you help me fix this problem?

Please, find below the we transfer link to download the datasets with 47 cells and with 160 cells.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/64cc631237adacc926c67f56124b327a20210928212223/d8a2d7

Thank you

Alexandre.

````
import geopandas as gpd
import time
import csv
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd

m = GEKKO()


A = -0.00000536 
B = -0.0000291 
E = 0.4040771 
r = 0.085 


input_path = 'D:/Alexandre/shapes/Threats/Prototype/BHO50k/Velhas_BHO50k1summ4_47cells.shp'


output_folder = 'D:/Alexandre/shapes/Threats/Prototype/Small_area/resultados'


input_layer = gpd.read_file(input_path)

input_layer = input_layer[
    ['cocursodag', 'cobacia', 'nuareacont', 'nudistbact', 'D0c', 'Ki0', 'Kj0', 'nuareamont', 'deltai', 'It',
     'cost_op_BR', 'Ii_ub', 'Itj', 'cj', 'deltaj2']]

input_layer = input_layer.astype({'cobacia': 'string', 'cocursodag': 'string'})


count_input_feat = input_layer.shape[0]


row=count_input_feat 
col=10 


input_cobacia = {}
ubi = {}
numareacont = {}
Ki0 = {}
Kj0 = {}
X = {}
deltai2 = {}
ai = {}
aj = {}
D0 = {}
Itj = {}
It = {}
deltaj = {}


for row1 in input_layer.iterrows():
    i = row1[0]

    input_cobacia[i] = row1[1]['cobacia'] 
    Ki0[i] = row1[1]['Ki0']+0.001 
    Kj0[i] = row1[1]['Kj0'] 
    X[i] = row1[1]['nuareamont'] 
    deltai2[i]  = row1[1]['deltai'] 
    ai[i] = 5423304*(pow(X[i],-0.1406852)) 
    aj[i] = row1[1]['cj']*100 + row1[1]['cost_op_BR']*100  
    ubi[i] = row1[1]['Ii_ub'] 
    numareacont[i] = row1[1]['nuareacont'] 
    D0[i] = row1[1]['D0c'] 
    It[i] = row1[1]['It'] 
    Itj[i] = row1[1]['Itj'] 
    if Itj[i]<1: 
        deltaj[i] = row1[1]['deltaj2'] * 0.0001
    elif Itj[i]<2:
        deltaj[i] = row1[1]['deltaj2'] * 0.0001
    else:
        deltaj[i] = row1[1]['deltaj2'] * 0.0001


Ii = m.Array(m.Var, (row, col))
Ij = m.Array(m.Var, (row, col))


for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        if It[i] == 0:
            Ii[i, j].value = 0
            Ii[i, j].lower = 0
            Ii[i, j].upper = 5
            Ij[i,j].value = 0
            Ij[i,j].lower = 0
            Ij[i,j].upper = numareacont[i]*0.05*Itj[i]/3.704545

        elif It[i] <= 2:
            Ii[i, j].value = 0
            Ii[i, j].lower = 0
            Ii[i, j].upper = 10
            Ij[i, j].value = 0
            Ij[i, j].lower = 0
            Ij[i, j].upper = numareacont[i]*0.05*Itj[i]/3.704545

        elif It[i] <= 2.5:
            Ii[i, j].value = 0
            Ii[i, j].lower = 0
            Ii[i, j].upper = 15
            Ij[i, j].value = 0
            Ij[i, j].lower = 0
            Ij[i, j].upper = numareacont[i]*0.05*Itj[i]/3.704545

        elif It[i] <= 3:
            Ii[i, j].value = 0
            Ii[i, j].lower = 0
            Ii[i, j].upper = 15
            Ij[i, j].value = 0
            Ij[i, j].lower = 0
            Ij[i, j].upper = numareacont[i]*0.05*Itj[i]/3.704545

        else:
            Ii[i,j].value = 0
            Ii[i,j].lower = 0
            Ii[i,j].upper = 20
            Ij[i,j].value = 0
            Ij[i,j].lower = 0
            Ij[i,j].upper = numareacont[i]*0.05*Itj[i]/3.704545


Ki = m.Array(m.Var, (row, col))
Kj = m.Array(m.Var, (row, col))
indicator = m.Array(m.Var, (row, col))
p = 2


numerator = m.Array(m.Var, (row, col))
denominator = m.Array(m.Var, (row, col))
for row2 in input_layer.iterrows():

    input_cobacia2 = row2[1]['cobacia']
    input_cocursodag = row2[1]['cocursodag']
    input_distance = row2[1]['nudistbact']

    numerator = 0
    denominator = 0

 
    exp = f"cobacia > '{input_cobacia2}' and cocursodag.str.startswith('{input_cocursodag}')"

    for j in range(col):
        for target_feat in input_layer.query(exp).iterrows(): 
            i=target_feat[0]
            target_green_area = Ij[i,j]
            target_distance = target_feat[1]['nudistbact']
            distance = float(target_distance) - float(input_distance)

            idw = 1 / (distance + 1) ** p
            numerator += target_green_area * idw
            denominator += idw



        i=row2[0]
        sum = Ij[i,j]

        if denominator:
            indicator[i,j] = numerator / denominator + sum
        else:
            indicator[i,j] = sum


D0F = m.Array(m.Var, (row, col)) 

for i in range(row): 
    def constraintD0(x):
        return x - 0.2
    for j in range(col): 
        if j == 0: 
            m.fix(Ki[i,j],val = Ki0[i])
            Ki[i,j].lower = 0
            Ki[i,j].upper = 500000
            m.fix(Kj[i,j], val = Kj0[i])
            Kj[i,j].lower = 0
            Kj[i,j].upper = 100000
            m.Equation(D0F[i, j] == A * Ki[i, j] + B * Kj[i, j] + E) 
            D0[i] = D0F[i, j]

        else:
            D0F[i,j].lower = 0
            D0F[i, j].upper = 1
            Ki[i,j].lower = 0
            Ki[i,j].upper = 500000
            Kj[i, j].lower = 0
            Kj[i, j].upper = 100000

            m.Equation(Ki[i,j] - Ki[i,j-1] == Ii[i,j] - deltai2[i] * Ki[i,j-1]) 
            m.Equation(Kj[i,j] - Kj[i,j-1] == Ij[i,j] + deltaj[i] * Kj[i,j-1]+indicator[i,j]) 
            m.Equation(D0F[i,j] == A*Ki[i,j] + B*Kj[i,j] + E)
            m.Equation(D0F[i,j]<=D0[i])

dep = 1 / (1+r) 


z1 = m.sum([m.sum([pow(dep, j)*(ai[i]*Ii[i,j]+aj[i]*Ij[i,j]) for i in range(row)]) for j in range(col)])

# Objective
m.Obj(z1)

m.options.IMODE = 3

m.options.SOLVER = 3

m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 1

m.options.REDUCE=3



try:

    m.solve()    # solve

    # Outputs
    output_Ki = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cobacia'] + list(range(col)))
    output_Kj = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cobacia'] + list(range(col)))
    output_Ii = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cobacia'] + list(range(col)))
    output_Ij = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cobacia'] + list(range(col)))
    output_D0 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cobacia'] + list(range(col)))
    output_ai = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cobacia'] + list(range(col)))
    output_aj = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cobacia'] + list(range(col)))

    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            print(Ki)


            output_Ii.loc[i, 'cobacia'] = input_cobacia[i]
            output_Ii.loc[i, j] = Ii[i,j].value[0]

            output_Ij.loc[i, 'cobacia'] = input_cobacia[i]
            output_Ij.loc[i, j] = Ij[i,j].value[0]

            output_Ki.loc[i, 'cobacia'] = input_cobacia[i]
            output_Ki.loc[i, j] = Ki[i,j].value[0]

            output_Kj.loc[i, 'cobacia'] = input_cobacia[i]
            output_Kj.loc[i, j] = Kj[i,j].value[0]

            output_D0.loc[i, 'cobacia'] = input_cobacia[i]
            output_D0.loc[i, j] = D0F[i, j].value[0]

            output_ai.loc[i, 'cobacia'] = input_cobacia[i]
            output_ai.loc[i, j] = ai[i]

            output_aj.loc[i, 'cobacia'] = input_cobacia[i]
            output_aj.loc[i, j] = aj[i]

    df_outputIi = pd.DataFrame(output_Ii)
    df_outputIj = pd.DataFrame(output_Ij)
    df_outputKi = pd.DataFrame(output_Ki)
    df_outputKj = pd.DataFrame(output_Kj)
    df_outputD0 = pd.DataFrame(output_D0)
    df_outputai = pd.DataFrame(output_ai)
    df_outputaj = pd.DataFrame(output_aj)


    with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
        df_outputIi.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="resultado Ii")
        df_outputIj.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="resultado Ij")
        df_outputKi.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="resultado Ki")
        df_outputKj.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="resultado Kj")
        df_outputD0.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="resultado D0")
        df_outputai.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="ai")
        df_outputaj.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="aj")

except:
    print('Not successful')
    from gekko.apm import get_file
    print(m._server)
    print(m._model_name)
    f = get_file(m._server,m._model_name,'infeasibilities.txt')
    f = f.decode().replace('\r','')
    with open('infeasibilities.txt', 'w') as fl:
        fl.write(str(f))


for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        print(Ki[i,j].value)
        print(Kj[i,j].value)
        print(D0F[i,j].value)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Look at the APMonitor model file `gk0_model.apm` in `m.path` by opening the run folder with `m.open_folder()`. Start with a smaller problem size and observe the equation size as the problem scales up. This limitation (<15,000 characters per equation) is built-in to encourage more efficient model expression and solution. An intermediate with `m.Intermediate()` can be used to more effectively express the model. [Additional information on Intermediates](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Intermediates) is available in the documentation.